# Web interface for c++ applications

Tags: c++, c, user-interface, qt

Our company has a set of 3d modeling softwares written in c++ with qt based gui. We are planning to offer these applications to customers to try them from a web browser. I mean to say, we need to create  web interfaces for native c++ codes. Please suggest me which technology, languages should be used. If possible please give some links to some white papers or case studies for this kind of projects. I am totally clue less :)

Answer (score 5):

Ideally you would keep your c++ code on the server and use a mixture of HTML and Javascript on the browser. However since  3d modeling is so client centric you may have to run some c++ code directly in the browser.

There are a few options to look at:

- [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/)
- [Adobe Alchemy](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/alchemy/)
- [Google Native Client](http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/)
- [A Java Applet using NestedVM](http://nestedvm.ibex.org/)
- [Netscape plugin API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Plugins)
- ActiveX

You could also run a few instances of your application on your server inside an [XVnc](http://www.realvnc.com/) session and let people use it through a VNC viewer applet. The simplest solution however is still to offer a downloadable demo of your application.

Comment: Or instead of duplicating code for NPAPI and ActiveX, using something like the Firebreath plugin framework: https://code.google.com/p/firebreath/

Comment: Have a look at the following blog post for an example of a Qt application running in a webbrowser using Google Native Client: http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2009/12/17/take-it-with-a-grain-of-salt/

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/)

Comment: Especially when you have a Qt background, you'll quickly find your way in Wt.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Native Client](http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/).

Answer (score 1):

Soon you might be use [WebGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL) to do 3D in the browser. But how long it will take for browsers to include it I do not know. But it might be good to look at it to not rule out using it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If creating everything again is too expensive, always you can create a distributed application:

- One program running the main application in C++ and generating (for example) XML files.
- A web application reading the XML files generated by the C++ application and translating them into the web application language (for example Adobe Flex).

Good luck!