# Running c++ in browser

Tags: c++, html

I have written some basic c++ programs in one of my classes for school. I was wondering if it was possible to somehow virtually run the program in a broswer. I would like to post the program to my website. Once its posted, a person could access the program, run the program, and, interact with the program. I'm not trying to write C++ for my website, it would be more for an interactive portfolio.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm worried by your phrasing "run the program in HTML". There are some general technological ideas that may relate to what you're thinking about, but I'm not sure at what level the best answer would be.

Comment: I'm confused: *Running c++ in browser* ... then, *I'm not trying to write C++ for my website*. If you have something you want to port functionality to a website (javascript, HTML, CSS), then that's what you need to do, with C++ handling any server callbacks if need be.

Comment: I clarified to "browser"

Comment: Some insight is offered in here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978540/web-interface-for-c-applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978540/web-interface-for-c-applications)

Comment: are you trying to "run" a graphical application or just something command line? what kind of access do you have to your web server (is it just ftp access or do you have full access)?

Comment: I doubt this is what you're looking for, but perhaps it will give you some ideas: http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/

Comment: @drewag I am just trying to run a command line application, very basic.

Comment: Are you looking for something like http://codepad.org/ ?

Comment: Shell in a box is something else you can consider.  Basically, you'd start a server process that runs your application, and use the AJAX component provided by the software to display the terminal emulator: http://code.google.com/p/shellinabox/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [codepad](http://codepad.org/), a website which lets you compile and [share code online](http://codepad.org/swcGBHog).

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::cout << "Hello, Stack Overflow!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is also [Google Native Client SDK](http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient-sdk/) that allows C++ code to run in browser. Microsoft Active X is also a viable option.   I am only saying it is possible not recommended.

Answer (score 3):

You can only run the program on your server, not on the client's machine.

At least not without downloading and manually executing it. Anything else would be an open door for malware...

Comment: Might need to update this a little bit. Entire full front-end apps, or apps with heavy logic running in the client are now common sense.

Answer (score 2):

I see two options, but both very overkill:

- Write (or find) a C++ interpreter in JavaScript
- Use a VM running an operating system (e.g. [jslinux](http://bellard.org/jslinux/) and demonstrate your programs there.

The sensible option is to just give people a way to view and download the source code, I guess.

Comment: I know of a project called Emscripten that can compile C and C++ source code to JavaScript. See here: http://bit.ly/1004X9a

Answer (score 2):

Google chrome supports this: http://www.readwriteweb.com/cloud/2011/08/google-officially-announces-cc.php

But it's by no means "mainstream" or standards-based.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Emscripten to compile C++ to Javascript. Emscripten can compile LLVM bitcode to Javascript. Some demos of Emscripten can be found [here](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki), including a raytracer and a text-to-speech engine that was compiled from C++ to Javascript.

To run x86 binaries in a web browser, you could also use an emulator such as [v86](https://github.com/copy/v86). This is one possible way to compile and run C++ programs in a browser.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution *(codepad like)* would be to use https://ideone.com/ which seems much nicer to use than codepad, more user-friendly, but does the same:

Allow you to write C++ (60 languages possibles) directly from the browser and compile it and render result in the browser (I tried using `printf` and it worked fine). Possibility of forking source code.

https://ideone.com/baYzfe

Answer (score 1):

One of the best sites for running C++ and other multiple languages online is [**Repl.it**](https://repl.it)

This example: [repl.it/@abranhe/stackoverflow](https://repl.it/@abranhe/stackoverflow)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
 
int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello Stackoverflow\n";
  return 0;
}
```

One of the biggest pros it has is that you can work with multiple files, working with header (`header.h`) files etc. None of the below websites provide this option:

- [Codepad.org](http://codepad.org/)
- [JSLinux](https://bellard.org/jslinux/vm.html?url=https://bellard.org/jslinux/buildroot-x86.cfg)
- [IDEone](https://ideone.com)

I really recommend it! You will love it!

Answer (score 0):

Also wanted to add [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/) here as an option:

**Cell 1:**

```
%%writefile hello.cpp
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::cout << "Hello, Stack Overflow!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

**Cell 2:**

```
%%script bash
g++ hello.cpp -o test
ls -laX
./test
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible and I can guarantee if you follow this tutorial you will be shocked about how  super easy is to use to C++ in a modern browser with [Cheerp](https://labs.leaningtech.com/cheerp)

Here is a simple example of how to combine you cpp file in js browser. For example, suppose that you have a project in which you need to sort a big array, and you want to replace the slow `Array.sort()` with a faster version. Instead of writing your own sorting function, you can use `std::sort()` from the C++ STL:

```
#include <cheerp/client.h>
#include <algorithm>

[[cheerp::jsexport]]
extern "C" void sort(client::Int32Array* a)
{
  int* begin = &(*a)[0];
  int* end = begin + (int)a->get_length();
  std::sort(begin, end);
}
```

You can compile the above code with `/opt/cheerp/bin/clang++ -target cheerp sort.cpp -o sort.js -cheerp-make-module=commonjs` and put the resulting sort.js in your project source folder. Than, using it is as easy as:

```
let cheerplib = require("./sort");
cheerplib.then((cl) => {
  let arr = new Int32Array([4, 2, 3, 1]);
  cl.sort(arr);
  console.log("Sorted with std::sort: " + arr);
});
```